# Different Device Orientation according to device (iPhone or iPad)

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

I'm working on a Universal project with these requirements:

- For iPhone, I want only the portrait orientation.
- For iPad, only landscapes.

How do I do that for **iOS 8** (Swift)?

Comment: have you tried the info.plist in Xcode?

Comment: Hi @ScarletMerlin . Thank you for your advice. I don't know how I missed the key "Supported interface orientations (iPad)". Using this key, it works according to the requirements. Feel free to create an answer so I can upvote. Cheers, mate.

Comment: don't worry I don't need the points from the approved answer. The info.plist is how you tell the iphone to handle global settings. you could also do it on code, but it is hardly ever recommended.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Following the advice of @ScarletMerlin , changing the keys in info.plist is, in my opinion, the best solution for the requirements I have to fulfill (fixed orientation type for each kind of device).

Here is a print screen from the settings I use. Maybe it can help other developers with similar doubt.

[image: Settings in info.plist file]

The relavent source code looks like this:

```xml
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Does this override whatever is checked under Target > General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check the hardware your application is running on. To do so, use this line of code.

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Then, once you have detected your hardware, block the orientation by using the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
}
```

Just as an example, you could do this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
    {
        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
            return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation); // If iPad
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation); // Else, it is an iPhone
    }
```