# iPhone and iPad Portrait mode app different reaction

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I have an app which I have locked to Portrait mode from project settings. Also should rotate is false etc. On the simulator (and devices) when I am on an iPhone device and rotate the labels and views stay on their places. But on the iPad when I change to landscape the views try to re-arrange. Why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: Check the accepted answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664441/different-device-orientation-according-to-device-iphone-or-ipad

Answer (score 0):

As mathew said try something like this

Following the advice of @ScarletMerlin , changing the keys in info.plist is, in my opinion, the best solution for the requirements I have to fulfill (fixed orientation type for each kind of device).

Here is a print screen from the settings I use. Maybe it can help other developers with similar doubt.

[image: Settings in info.plist file]

The relavent source code looks like this:

```xml
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```