# Supported interface orientations on iPhone/iPad using Cordova config.xml

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ipad

Following from: [Different Device Orientation according to device (iPhone or iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664441/different-device-orientation-according-to-device-iphone-or-ipad)

I can successfully setup orientations on iPhone/iPad differently in XCode as follows:

[image: Different Orientations]

However, this info.plist will be overwritten everytime I run cordova build. Therefore, my question is: how to use config.xml to setup the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add entry to iOS .plist file via Cordova config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769111/add-entry-to-ios-plist-file-via-cordova-config-xml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i set different orientations for IPad and IPhone (Universal) app in cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497799/can-i-set-different-orientations-for-ipad-and-iphone-universal-app-in-cordova)

Comment: DaveAlden is correct, thanks a lot.